# Playwright - Azure AD - OAuth 2.0 authentication issues in executing tests

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, playwright

Have this below playwright node.js script for login page UI test. The site is Azure AD OAuth 2 enabled (with MFA - authenticator enabled).

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { generateToken } from 'authenticator';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
test.setTimeout(50000);
await page.goto('https://prod-site.com/'); // This URL is Azure AD MFA enabled and hence 
// should redirect to MFA page but not happening in Azure DevOps pipeline
// Expecting the URL  https://login.microsoftonline.com/ may be ? but I don't want this 
//as playwright should automatically  redirect (happens locally in the machine)
//But fails in Azure DevOps pipeline: 
//await page.goto('https://login.microsoftonline.com/');
await page.getByPlaceholder('Email, phone, or Skype').fill('user@prod-site.com');
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next' }).click();
await page.locator('#i0118').fill('password');
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
await page.getByPlaceholder('Code').fill(generateToken('code'));
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Verify' }).click();
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Yes' }).click();
await page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Welcome to prod-site' }).click(); 
});
```

The above code works fine in the local machine but fails in the Azure DevOps pipeline with the following error

**locator.fill: Target closed: waiting for getByPlaceholder('Email, phone, or Skype')**

Could you please unblock from this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the token grant flow you are using? And even the redirect success, [MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks) should have interactive operations, pipeline can't interactive login.

Comment: You mentioned it works on local, will it pop out MFA auth window when you run it on local?

Comment: Yes, it gets autofilled. I am using authenticator.generateToken('code') to pass the MFA.

Comment: Could be that your test AD and the one your pipeline uses are different versions and have different HTML for the 'Email, phone, or Skype' label. I currently have to match on the placeholder: 'Email or phone' (no skype)